# $aggregation and $look up in the same collection- mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

The structure is more or less like;

```
[   
    {id: 1, name: "alex" , children: [2, 4, 5]},
    {id: 2, name: "felix", children: []},
    {id: 3, name: "kelly", children: []},
    {id: 4, name: "hannah", children: []},
    {id: 5, name: "sonny", children: [6]},
    {id: 6, name: "vincenzo", children: []}
]
```

I want to replace `children` id's with names when `children` array is not empty.

So the result of the query is expected as;

```
[   {id: 1, name: "alex" , children: ["felix", "hannah" , "sonny"]}
    {id: 5, name: "sonny", children: ["vincenzo"]}
]
```

What have I done to achieve this;

```
db.list.aggregate([
  {$lookup: { from: "list", localField: "id", foreignField: "children", as: "children" }},
  {$project: {"_id" : 0, "name" : 1, "children.name" : 1}},
])
```

filled children with its parent, which is not what I want :)

```
{ "name" : "alex", "parent" : [ ] }
{ "name" : "felix", "parent" : [ { "name" : "alex" } ] }
{ "name" : "kelly", "parent" : [ ] }
{ "name" : "hannah", "parent" : [ { "name" : "alex" } ] }
{ "name" : "sonny", "parent" : [ { "name" : "alex" } ] }
{ "name" : "vincenzo", "parent" : [ { "name" : "sonny" } ] }
```

What did I misunderstood?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before use `$lookup` stage you should use `$unwind` for children array then `$lookup` for children. After `$lookup` stage you need to use `$group` to get children array with **name** instead of **id**

You can try it:

```
db.list.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$children"},
    {$lookup: { 
        from: "list",
        localField: "children",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "childrenInfo" 
      }
    },
    {$group:{
       _id:"$_id",
       children:{$addToSet:{$arrayElemAt:["$childrenInfo.name",0]}},
       name:{$first:"$name"}
      }
    }
]);

// can use $push instead of $addToSet if name can be duplicate
```

**Why used `$group` ?**

For example:
your first document

```
{id: 1, name: "alex" , children: [2, 4, 5]}
```

after `$unwind` your document will be look like

```
{id: 1, name: "alex" , children: 2},
{id: 1, name: "alex" , children: 4},
{id: 1, name: "alex" , children: 5}
```

after `$lookup`

```
{id: 1, name: "alex" , children: 2,
  "childrenInfo" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name" : "felix",
            "children" : []
        }
    ]},
//....
```

then after `$group`

```
 {id: 1, name: "alex" , children: ["felix", "hannah" , "sonny"]}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understood my mistake about `localField` and `foreignField`. But can you explain the `$group` in the query?

Comment: because of `$unwind` the *children* array to make it separate document for each *children* and then again to make it array of *children* need to use `$group`. can see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-array

Comment: Like the fact that you showed the current state after each aggregation method - makes it much easier to follow. +1

Answer (score 5):

With the current Mongo 3.4 version you can make use of `$graphLookup`.

`$maxDepth` set at `0` for a non-recursive lookup. You may want to add a  `$match` stage before the lookup to filter the records with no children.

```
db.list.aggregate([{
    $graphLookup: {
        from: "list",
        startWith: "$children",
        connectFromField: "children",
        connectToField: "id",
        as: "childrens",
        maxDepth: 0,
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": 1,
        "childrenNames": "$childrens.name"
    }
}]);
```